# Works Cited multiple pages in powerpoint

Tags: mla

I am making a powerpoint presentation and I have 3 slides that are for Works Cited.

I currently have it as 
Works Cited (I)
Works Cited (II)
Works Cited (III)

for the titles of the slides.

Is this correct? Is there a better way to title?

Comment: I don't think MLA has any guidelines for this.

Comment: What are your doubts, please? If you want to cut those names down to, for instance, WCI, II & III go ahead and otherwise, why is there a query?